# Determining inactive records in a table

Tags: sql, bigdata

In this scenario, "inactive" can generally refer to data that has not been accessed in the last month by users from the web server.

Knowing the "inactive" status of records can be used to optimize queries for the active data as the database table grows larger.

---

I know one approach can be to

1. Update a record with a `last_accessed` timestamp each time it is 
   accessed.
2. Monthly, when there is low traffic, the web server can tell the database to update an `inactive` flag for records that have/have not been accessed in the past month.

But two major issues to this approach are

1. Updating when the client is just trying to select data has a performance impact.
2. If there are too many records, the monthly update may take too long and cause issues, like locking rows.

Wondering what a better, or alternative approach could be.

Comment: I simply cannot fathom how updating a zillion records with an inactive status could be used to increase performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am thinking they can be partitioned off or use a filtered index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach.

You could write a query that would essentially check if the `last_accessed_date` is in the last 30 days (`CASE WHEN last_accessed_date < SYSDATE-30`) and created an `is_active` indicator. That would essentially allow you to mark the historic records as active or inactive.

Then, once you have this done, you would need to run this script routinely (daily, weekly, or monthly) to check the status of these items. Monthly might be a good idea, and do it during a non-business hour so it does not affect performance much (Saturday mornings at 3:00AM). I'm sure you could schedule this with your team and also have your communications team send out a notice to the end users that they may see usability delays during this timeframe (first Saturday of the month from 3:00 AM - 6:00 AM or something).

Additionally, you could have it be the case that there is a second condition. Whenever someone does access a record, you could have a small logic check that essentially says "Change the last_accessed_date to today. If is_active is currently No, switch to yes". That would keep your database more up to date.

A last piece, for optimization, is if you choose to include the second option (the logic check), you could have a field that says "Last_Updated_Indicator" which is the date that the indicator was last changed. If your last updated indicator is within the lead time since you last ran your entire database update function, it can be skipped. This would drastically cut down on the performance impact of that update procedure.

Comment: To your last point, I think having a `last_updated_indicator` is redundant, since `last_accessed_date` would be the same.